# GIT INIT not creating a working tree

Tags: git, git-bare, git-init

I'm doing a simple `git init C:\XXX` running from my master machine to be executed on another slave machine. `C:\XXX` is a path in the slave. The assumption is that it would create a non bare repository as I did not provide a `--bare` option. Also I looked at the system, global config settings in the slave machine and specifically set the `bare = false` option in these. But even then after running the `git init` I can see the local config having `bare = true`.

From where does the init command takes the bare settings by default?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the roles of the master machine and the slave machine are here. Is `C:\XXX` accessible from both? Do the two machines have different system or global settings? (For instance, if you ran `git init C:\XXX` on machine A, then it is only the settings in A's configuration files that matter.)

Comment: I have this jenkins job configured to be run on a slave. The job has a series of git commands using a workspace directory in slave. C:\XXX is the workspace directory in slave. When jenkins executes the git init command it is a creating a bare repository. I tried to display the git config --list before the init and none of the bare settings are set to true but I do the same after the init command and I see one bare=true entry.  I also tried directly executing these commands from slave machine command prompt and it does create a non bare repository that way

Comment: what is the global setting for `bare` on the master machine?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git init <path>` on your master machine, the Git app is run on master. It uses global configs of that machine, where you probably have `bare=true`.

To solve this you can use one of these options:

1. Login to slave machine with SSH and run `git init <path>`
2. Directly copy a premade `.git` to selected path on slave. This gives you an option to use tweaked repository. E.g. you can add git hooks.

Comment: Got it resolved!! It somehow had to do with the slave machine I created. I updated lot of config files to have bare = false and probably messed up something . So I deleted the slave and created another slave and used the slave.jar that I needed for starting the new one.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. Nick -> the git init was being run on the slave machine as the jenkins job was running on the slave and it was using the slave git also as I provided the tool location with slave git path

Comment: @ARUNNAIR oh, I see. Would you mind if I rewrite my answer to include your solution?

Comment: Sure Nick. Please go ahead